# Pattern matching and replacment - one or more of the same pattern/character

Tags: r, replace, pattern-matching

I'd like to replace one or more than one full-stop in my strings with a blank.

I've tried the following, but either none of the full-stops gets replaced with a blank, or the entire string gets replaced with a blank.

```
# Toy Data
book = c("eggs.", "flour...", "..butter", "bakingpowder", "coco..dark")

# Attempt at replacing full stops with blanks
gsub(".+", "", book)

sub("(.+)", "", book)

gsub(".\\+", "", book)

sub("(.\\+)", "", book)

# Expected result
book = c("eggs", "flour", "butter", "bakingpowder", "cocodark")
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to escape the dot `\.` (or double escape `\\.`) to match it literally

Comment: `gsub("\\.", "", book)`